# JQuery/DOM event for typing Chinese (ibus)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cjk, ime

as we know there is a lot of events will be triggered when we typing.

such as keyup, keydown, keypress or something else.

Is there any other event will be triggered only when the content in the text field is changed? and if there is not,how to write some javasrcipt code to accomplish this feature

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more on your use case? perhaps only way to achieve that is providing a web-based input methods your self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event might help?

Comment: No,because the change does detect whether the content in the field is changed or not,but it won't be triggered unless you press enter or the field lost focus

Comment: Before you commit your string ( such as press "enter"), the string is actually stored in the preedit buffer of input method. i.e. Browser won't know what exactly what you type before you commit the string.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple fiddle to determine what happens when a text node in a contenteditable element is modified by a key press. As I was doing that, I decided to check what happens when using ibus because I use ibus for my own work. I determined that when ibus is used, the only keyboard event generated is a keyup event with a `which` value which is useless.

Here is the fiddle I created:

http://jsfiddle.net/lddubeau/jWnL3/

1. Go to that fiddle.
2. Turn on your Javascript console.
3. Click run.
4. Click between the 2dn and third character of the word "toto".
5. Type something using ibus. For instance, type 我.
6. The output varies depending on your browser. On Chrome 29 each keystroke is recorded so if I type 我 using the tonepy method I get keyup and keydown for each of the "w" "o" "3" and "1". (The pinyin, the tone and then hitting 1 to select the first choice.) The final event is:

   ```
   event type: keyup
   which: 229
   keyCode: 229
   charCode: 0
   node value: 
      to我to
   ```

   The events before this one all have the same values except that some are of the "keydown" type and of course the node value shows "toto" until the last event.

   On Firefox 23 only one event is registered:

   ```
   "event type:" "keyup"
   "which:" 49
   "keyCode:" 49
   "charCode:" 0
   "node value:" "
       to我to
   "
   ```

   No keydown or keypress events are generated. (When typing characters within the ascii range, you get keydown, keypress and keyup for each key.)

The values of which and keyCode do not seem to correspond to anything sensible. I've examined the event object passed to the event handler and did not see any field which would indicate that the user just typed 我.